# Como usar caractere de escape no CSS?

Tags: css

Estou tentando inserir um caractere especial no `:before` dos meus links para que fiquem da seguinte maneira:

➔ Esse é o link

O problema é que esse caractere é escrito em hexadecimal e quando eu tento colocá-lo no `content:'&#10132;'` ao invés de exibir a figura exibe o valor hexadecimal dele e fica assim:

```
&#10132; Esse é o link
```

**Existe algum caractere de escape CSS?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente usar o caractere literal (como observado pelo Emerson Rocha Luiz, o arquivo CSS - e possivelmente também o HTML - deve ser salvo com o encoding UTF-8):

```
a:before { content: "➔"; }
```

Ou o código unicode do caractere em formato hexadecimal, escapado com `\`. Você estava usando o código 10132 em decimal, que é 2794 em hexadecimal:

```
a:before { content: "\2794"; }
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9PeY/)</sup>

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto, esse segundo exemplo que você sugeriu ficou top, é que eu não queria usar o caractere literal rs. Como você consegue o código unicode do caractere?

Comment: O código que você está usando no HTML é em decimal, é só converter pra hexa. Existem também tabelas e listas de caracteres com os respectivos códigos, como http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm

Comment: Uma adição importante é mencionar o encoding do arquivo. Pelo que lembro deve ser salvo em UTF-8 ou outro que suporte os caracteres, ou vai ficar uma bagunça.

Comment: Obrigado @EmersonRochaLuiz, atualizei.

Comment: Não precisa citar nome no post ahahaha. Era só por mesmo. Hoje em dia quase sempre tudo é UTF8, mas já tive problemas com isso e foi complicado até ver que era só isso.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Eu tenho esse hábito de citar :) Eu também uso tudo em UTF-8 há alguns anos, mas talvez o autor da pergunta não use mesmo.