# Como colocar caracteres especiais com ::after?

Tags: css

Aqui está o código, quero colocar o caractere © :

```css
h1::after{
 content: &#169;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Como usar caractere de escape no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5558/como-usar-caractere-de-escape-no-css)

Comment: Relacionado: [Como colocar &raquo e &laquo no ::before?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88788/como-colocar-raquo-e-laquo-no-before/88790#88790)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significa content:"\f0ed"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75162/3635) e [Como colocar &raquo e &laquo no ::before?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88788/3635)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar caracter unicode do CSS, exemplo:

```css
h1::after{
  content:"\00a9";
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Empresa
</h1>
```

[Lista de caracteres especiais](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/)

Comment: Você sabe como deixar esse caractere sobrelinhado(em HTML usa-se a tag <sup>)???

Comment: @nelson450 veja minha edição.

Comment: não era isso que quis dizer, eu queria ela com o efeito de algo como "x ao quadrado"

Comment: @nelson450 veja a edição agora.

Comment: @nelson450 Muito bom, mas você pode também simplesmente trocar a position e tudo abaixo por: `vertical-align: super;`

Comment: @LeonFreire sim, também funciona :)